# Prestashop PHP mail not working

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I was looking for a solution here without a luck. I can't send mails from my prestashop using mail() function. I've tested with my own .php file and it works flawlessly, but in presta receive just an error.

I've looked up that my phpinfo has empty "from" value, but I don't know if that's an issue.

What can be the solution? I know that Presta is using swiftmail.

Comment: Are you trying to send email from localhost or a web server?

Comment: web serwer. I even tried SMTP with freshly creater gmail account without a luck.

Comment: At this point I guess you have a problem with hosting configuration

Comment: Did you enabled less secure apps option in your newly created gmail account?

Comment: When order is confirmed, prestashop sends email to customer?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try sending email in Advanced Preferences -> Mail -> Sent a test message (bottom of page)?
Whether the script / module that sending emails, as he does the translations necessary (eg if you send email in Italian, must emails to be translated into Italian).

Regards

Answer (score 0):

To send email from Prestashop, you have to configure SMTP by clicking on 
`Advanced Preferences -> E-Mail`.

A form will be open where you have to enter this :

```
Server: smtp.gmail.com (if you uses gmail)

Username: your gmail id

Password: your gmail password

Encryption: SSL

Port: 465
```

Then, write code in PHP to send mail using `send()` function of class `MailCore.php`